# How to get started on this project?

Tags: java, javascript, constructor, client, java-7

I'm struggling to understand the instructions for my project, english is my second language so can someone help break it down and assist me in how i would go about this project?

**Project Summary**
   Write a program that produces statistics for a baseball team.

**Instructions:**

Create the BaseballStats class:

It has two instance variables:
       teamName, a String
       battingAverages,  an arrays of doubles representing the batting averages of all the players on the team.

The class has the following API:

**Constructor:**

```
  public BaseballStats( String filename )
```

The team name and the batting averages for the team are stored in the file. You can assume the first item in the file is the team name (one word – no spaces), followed by exactly 20 batting averages. Your constructor should read the file into the teamName instance variable and the battingAverages array.

**Methods:**

```
 public String getTeamName( )
    accessor for teamName

 public void setTeamName( String newTeamName )
    mutator for teamName

 public double maxAverage( )
   returns the highest batting average

 public double minAverage( )
   returns the lowest batting average

 public double spread( )
   returns the difference between the highest and lowest batting averages

 public int goodPlayers( )
   returns the number of players with an average higher than .300

 public String toString( )
     returns a String containing the team name followed by all the batting averages formatted to three decimal places.
```

**Client class:**

Your client should instantiate an object of the BaseballStats class, passing the name of the text file containing the team name and the averages. The client should then call all methods, reporting the results as output.

Comment: So what do you not understand? The first step as the instructions say is to create the BaseballStats class. Have you done that? If not start with that, then try the next instruction.

Comment: I dont understand how to get the class file started

Comment: Are you using an IDE? like eclipse?

Comment: Do you have a text book? Or are you following a tutorial? Did your instructor give you notes or demonstrated building a class?

Comment: I've been going through the text book but im not getting much help from it, are instructors notes were very basic an again its not really helping me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've perhaps never used Java before judging by your comment. Here is how it should be laid out:

```
class BaseballStats {

private String filename;

public BaseballStats ( String filename )
{
    this.filename = filename;
}

public String getTeamName( )
{
//accessor for teamName
}

public void setTeamName( String newTeamName )
{
//mutator for teamName
}

public double maxAverage( )
{
//returns the highest batting average
}
public double minAverage( )
{
//returns the lowest batting average
}

public double spread( )
{
//returns the difference between the highest and lowest batting averages
}

public int goodPlayers( )
{
//returns the number of players with an average higher than .300
}

public String toString( )
{
//returns a String containing the team name followed by all the batting averages formatted to three decimal places. 
}
}
```

Your client (a different java file in the same directory) can create an instance of this class with:

```
BaseballStats newTeam = new BaseballStats(filename);
```

Comment: Its my first semester with java, Im searching for how to get the team name and batting averages out of the the text file so i can use them but am having no luck

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716623/1758149

Comment: we have never used bufferedreaders so its something we cant use it in our programs

Comment: Have you used Scanner()?